# Mysql - Help for optimizing query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT bi.id, 
       bi.location, 
       bi.expense_group, 
       bi.level, 
       bi.is_active, 
       bi.type, 
       full_name, 
       ( bl.bud_amount )                                     AS BudgetAmount, 
       ( COALESCE(( ( bl.bud_amount * 3 ) - ( 
                    + bal.bal_amount1 + bal.bal_amount2 
                    + bal.bal_amount3 ) ), 0) ) AS Difference, 
       ( COALESCE(Round(( + bal.bal_amount1 + bal.bal_amount2 
                          + bal.bal_amount3 ) / 3), 0) )     AS Average, 
       bal.bal_amount1                                       AS BAL1, 
       bal.bal_amount2                                       AS BAL2, 
       bal.bal_amount3                                       AS BAL3 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   budget_items bi 
        WHERE  bi.location IS NOT NULL) AS bi 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT budget_item_id, 
                         Sum(CASE 
                               WHEN budget_id = 21491 THEN amount 
                             END) AS bud_amount 
                  FROM   budget_lines 
                  GROUP  BY budget_item_id) AS bl 
              ON bl.budget_item_id = bi.id 
       JOIN (SELECT budget_item_id, 
                    Ifnull(Sum(CASE 
                                 WHEN balance_id = 12841 THEN amount 
                               END), 0) AS bal_amount1, 
                    Ifnull(Sum(CASE 
                                 WHEN balance_id = 18647 THEN amount 
                               END), 0) AS bal_amount2, 
                    Ifnull(Sum(CASE 
                                 WHEN balance_id = 18674 THEN amount 
                               END), 0) AS bal_amount3 
             FROM   balance_lines 
             GROUP  BY budget_item_id) AS bal 
         ON bal.budget_item_id = bi.id 
ORDER  BY bi.location
```

It takes a lot of time. In the budget_lines and balance_lines tables I have more than 5,000,000 rows in each.

I also attach the EXPLAIN of the query, so you'll ne able to see the problem.
All ids in every table are indexed. Is there any column that if would be indexed spped up the query? Or maybe I need to change it.

*** LEFT JOIN is necessary because I need to get all the items from nudget_items, even if they don't exist in the balance/budget_line table.

Schema is: every budget has its budget_lines. Every balance has its balance_lines. The query is aimed to have ONE table to summarize the differences between a budget and several balances.

[image]

You can see a bigger image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlF8V.png

**EDIT:**
After @Sebas answers:
[image]

For @sabes hunger, I put here the DESCRIBE:
budget_items
[image]

budget_lines
[image]

balance_lines
[image]

Comment: _I also attach the EXPLAIN of the query..._ (you did?)

Comment: your tables `bal` and `bl` apparently only sum the values for certain `balance_id`. You should add it in a where clause of their respective subqueries.

Comment: @Sebas since this query is complicated - can you show me exactly what you mean?

Comment: I don't want to post it because it is not really an answer, but basically you could add `WHERE balance_id IN (12841, 18647, 18674)` in the subquery of table `bal`

Comment: the ifnull(Sum stuff... are you saying that if the amount is 0 at any time for a balance_ID then you want 0 returned? So if 10 records exist  and 1 is null and the other 9 show 100 each you want 0 returned and not 900?

Comment: similarly with `budget_id = 21491` for table `tb`

Comment: @Sebas - I put the new EXPLAIN that I get now. It seems a great improvement, so why do you say that it is not an answer?

Comment: Scary query - if you flatten out the subqueries it should improve the performance a lot (using a subquery for bl is just silly). And there's very little filtering in the query - it's going to produce a LOT of output - is anyone ever going to read this or have you not shown us the queries you actually run?

Comment: Because that's just a drop in the sea. There are many more things to do. We probably need the exact DESCRIBE TABLE results to go further on then

Comment: @symcbean - Yes, it is a real query. Later I manipulate it in a HTML page. Adding color and more scary things to make it nicer.

Comment: @Sebas - On which tables should I run it?

Comment: all, we love DESCRIBE statements, haha.

Comment: @NoamB., I see there are multiple columns keys, could you confirm how they compound together please? And also the order of the columns in the indices please. After that I'll have a deeper look.

Comment: As I explained in my question: every balance has many balance_lines. Every budget has many budget_lines. Every budget line has one of the budget_items ids, but some budget_items can be multiple times in a budget, so they will be also multiple in the budget_lines. parent_id can be mutiple because a parent can have more than one child that he pays for. I did not understand your request regarding the columns in the indices.

Comment: Can you see the column "key"? When it says "mul" it means there's a compound index. I need to know the exact composition of the indices.

Comment: I am not sure what you need. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this; but without sample data, and indexes it's difficult to see

```
SELECT * 
FROM   budget_items bi 
WHERE  bi.location IS NOT NULL) AS bi 
INNER JOIN  --Added inner for clarity  -changed order I just like my inner's before my outers.
  (SELECT budget_item_id, Sum(CASE WHEN balance_id = 12841 THEN coalesce(amount,0) END), 0) AS bal_amount1, 
                          Sum(CASE WHEN balance_id = 18647 THEN coalesce(amount,0) END), 0) AS bal_amount2, 
                          Sum(CASE WHEN balance_id = 18674 THEN coalesce(amount,0) END), 0) AS bal_amount3 
   FROM   balance_lines 
   WHERE balance_ID in (12841, 18647, 18674) --This way balance_IDs which aren't in this list don't even get evaluated
   GROUP  BY budget_item_id) AS bal 
 ON bal.budget_item_id = bi.id 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT budget_item_id, Sum(CASE WHEN budget_id = 21491 THEN coalesce(amount,0) END) AS bud_amount 
  FROM   budget_lines 
  WHERE budget_Id = 21491 --Again since we only care about anything but budget_ID 21491, we can limit the results to JUST that 
  GROUP  BY budget_item_id) AS bl 
 ON bl.budget_item_id = bi.id
```

Comment: Is this different from @Sabes answers?

Comment: only that I eliminated the IIFs making the assumption that you didn't really want 0 when 1 record could be NULL.